# Expand the treeViewItem when mouse is over

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview, mouseover

I'm working using WPF, and I'm dealing with the treeViewItem. I'm looking for a way to expand the node when the mouse is over this node, and set `IsExpand=false` property when the mouse is not over there. It's quite simple the functionality.

I'm a bit lost using the events for this controls, if should I use the triggers or the events.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someting like this should point you in the right direction

```
<Grid>
    <TreeView Margin="0,40,0,0">
        <TreeViewItem Header="Level 1">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Level 2" />
        </TreeViewItem>

        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="False" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: `<Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding Path=IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />` should work also.